# Different audio by language

Tags: android, audio

Different audio by language.

Hello, I wonder if it is possible to use different audio tracks according to the user's language, similar to strings.xml  but for sound files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using raw resources for the audio tracks, you can have different resource set qualifiers for those (e.g., `res/raw-es/`), just as you can for strings (e.g., `res/values-es/`). Your Java code would refer to `R.raw.whatever` (where `whatever` is the base name for the track), and Android would pull in the correct raw resource based on the locale.

Comment: Thanks very good, did not know it was that simple.